# Variable initialised in Constructor is null, but initialised in class method works

Tags: c++, qt, zeromq

I am currently trying to do the following in my Application:

```
#include "zmqworker.h"
#include <QDebug>

ZMQWorker::ZMQWorker(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    zmq::context_t ctx;
    zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, zmq::socket_type::dealer);

    qDebug() << "Dealer Socket created";

}

void ZMQWorker::connectSocket()
{
//    zmq::context_t ctx;
//    std::string origin="CPP_ZMQ";

    sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    qDebug() << sock;
    qDebug() << "Dealer Socket connected";

}
```

I am trying to create a socket in the constructor which definitely get's called. And in the connect function I am trying to connect to the zmq socket. which throws an Exception since sock is 0x0. If I do all parts in the connectSocket function it works without a problem and sock is not null.

Since I am only used to languages like Java, Python, JavaScript and Go this behaviour does not make sense for me and while I could try out till I find a solution I don't want to come to a situation that I just get something where it works but I do not understand it.

Application is QT6.2
C++20 / CMake

Comment: `sock` is destroyed when it goes out of scope, make it a data member.

Comment: You are not showing your full code. Please provide a [mre]. But anyway: `zmq::socket_t sock(ctx, zmq::socket_type::dealer);` does not initialize the class member named `sock`. It creates a new function-local variable named `sock` that lives until the end of the function. You are initializing a class member (rather base class) correctly in the member initializer list: `QObject{parent}`. Do the same for `sock`.

Comment: ok of course ... #facepalm

Answer (score 1):

For reference this is what user17732522 is referring to

```
#include "zmqworker.h"
#include <QDebug>

ZMQWorker::ZMQWorker(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent},

     sock(ctx, zmq::socket_type::dealer)
{



    qDebug() << "Dealer Socket created";


}

void ZMQWorker::connectSocket()
{
    std::string origin="CPP_ZMQ";
    sock.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    qDebug() << "Dealer Socket connected";

}
```

Comment: please accept the corrected answer

Comment: you didn't show the contents of zmqworker.h which means we don't know the order of initialization of the class members. For example, if you were to add `ctx(0)` to your initialization list, you would get a different outcome depending on the relative order of definition of `ZMQWorker.sock` and `ZMQWorker.ctx`. This is why we ask for a minimal viable example.